# How to solve Stochastic differential equation?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I do not have a clue on how to solve out this type of question, and how to deal with integration with a combination of brownian motion and linear function. Can anyone help me out please?

[image]

Comment: Plug in and simplify. You should introduce a second dummy integration variable to do so.

Comment: I have tried to use integration by parts for (1-t) and the integration and tried plugging it in but I am stuck at computing the double integration of Bs over (1-s)^2  wrt to dt.

Comment: @Dr.MV I appreciate your help, I am very sorry that I do not know how to solve this.

Comment: @Cheri  I added considerably to the original HINT.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.

Comment: @Dr.MV I have got a similar question and I used substitution and I got an extra term, can you kindly help me have a look at that question? 

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273156/how-to-show-stochastic-differential-equation-is-given-by-an-equation

Comment: @cheri I will try and look at this later.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

$$\int_0^t\int_0^{s}\frac{B_s'}{(1-s')^2}ds'ds=\int_0^t\int_s'^t
\frac{B_s'}{(1-s')^2}ds'ds \tag 1$$

and

$$\int_0^t \frac{B_s'(t-s')}{(1-s')^2}ds'=\int_0^t \frac{B_s'(t-1+1-s')}{(1-s'^2)}ds' \tag 2$$

Can you complete?

---

We are given

$$X_t=xt+B_t-(1-t)\int_0^t \frac{B_s}{(1-s)^2}ds \tag 3$$

and asked to show that this $X_t$ is a solution of the following

$$X_t=B_t+\int_0^t \frac{x-X_s}{1-s}ds \tag 4$$

Let's substitute $(3)$ into $(4)$ to obtain

$$\begin{align}
X_t&=xt+B_t-(1-t)\int_0^t \frac{B_s}{(1-s)^2}ds\\\\
&=B_t+\int_0^t \frac{x-(xs+B_s-(1-s)\int_0^t \frac{B_s'}{(1-s')^2}ds')}{(1-s)}ds\\\\
&=B_t+xt-\int_0^s \frac{B_s}{(1-s)}ds+\int_0^t \int_0^s \frac{B_s'}{(1-s')^2}ds'ds \tag 5
\end{align}$$

Using Hints $(1)$ and $(2)$,

$$\int_0^t \int_0^s \frac{B_s'}{(1-s')^2}ds'ds=\int_0^t \frac{B_s}{1-s}ds-(1-t)\int_0^t \frac{B_s}{(1-s)^2}ds$$

and we are done!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this is very helpful!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.