# How to do integration by parts with brownian motion?

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am not sure how to perform integration by parts in the following expression:
$$
   \left(1-t\right)\left(B_t - B_s + \int_s^t \frac{r}{1-r} \mathrm{d} B_r \right)
$$
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you know you want to perform integration by parts?

Comment: Hint: Integration by parts originates from the product rule for derivates. Do you know how to determine $d( f_t g_t)$ for two stochastic processes $f_t$ and $g_t$?

Comment: is this related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273156/how-to-show-stochastic-differential-equation-is-given-by-an-equation/1276933#1276933) problem?

Comment: Yes that's in my past exam paper from last year, I went to my lecturer's office hour and he told me to perform integration by parts to get the differentiation and make it look like the solution of SDE. I am confused when come to solving the integration by parts to this expression.